# How can I pull in dates from a cell next to the one I'm querying?

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I'm trying to pull in the top 5 and bottom 5 results for my data set into a table which I've done using the =MAX(C:C) formula and then =LARGE(C:C,2), =LARGE(C:C,3) for the next largest ones etc.

What I'd like to do in the next cell to these results is to be able to have the date that the results lie on. How can I do this?

e.g.

Column A  Top 5 results: 15.46% 14.10% 13.74% 13.42% 13.15%

Column B   Date: Needs to query the date that this 15.46% comes from in the cell next to it in the data set

What formula should I use to get the correct date to appear next to the column A results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the values in column **C** and dates in column **D**, in **A1** enter:

```
=LARGE(C:C,ROWS($1:1))
```

and copy downward.  In **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A1,C:C,0))
```

and copy downward:

[image]

*(You should also consider `VLOOKUP()`)*

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's really helpful. If I want to add another column to see how many days from each date in column B the value in A had taken to reduce by 10% (based on the original data set in your example this is in columns C & D), how would I create that formula? Thanks, I appreciate your help.